# [attr.disabled]="isChecked == true ? ' ' : disabled"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router, angular8

[attr.disabled]="isChecked == true ? '' : disabled"
I want to disabled unchecked checkbox in loop.please helpme.angular 8

[attr.disabled]="isChecked == true ? '' : disabled".in angular 8

Comment: You should use "null" to not show the attribute: `[attr.disabled]="rateDetails.isChecked ?null:true "` If the attribute disabled is in a tag it's disabled whatever the attribute value

Comment: One thing I wonder, how would you make a disabled checkbox enabled again?

Answer (score 1):

Try `[disabled]="isChecked"`. disabled attribute is a boolean attribute. So it requires either true or false

Sample code below:

HTML Code

```
<div *ngFor="let a of array, let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" (click)="onClick(i)" [disabled]="checkedStatus[i]" >{{i}}
</div>
```

TS Code

```
array=[1,2,3,4,5];
checkedStatus = new Array(5).fill(false);

onClick(index) {
  this.checkedStatus[index] = true;
}
```

Comment: Check box is in a loop. I want the non checked  details should be disabled

Comment: How I can disabled unchecked details in disabled

Comment: Could you post the html code?

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let rateDetails of purchaseOrderDetails.poRateContractDetails, let rowIndex = index">
                                    <td>{{rowIndex+1}}</td>
                              
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="shortlist" [(ngModel)]="rateDetails.isChecked" (click)="onChangeActive($event)" [attr.disabled]="isChecked == true ? '' : disabled"  >
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>

Comment: Will there be only one check box be disabled at a time?

Comment: No.more than one

Comment: I've updated the answer based on the comments